# Hide mySQL error from invalid URL

Tags: mysql

I have a site with 300 articles stored in a mySQL database with the URL format of www.site.com/article1.html.

Most invalid URLs redirect succesfully to the main site.  For example, www.site.com/article301 redirects to www.site.com, which is what I want.

But www.site.com/article301.html does not redirect anywhere.  Instead it loads a blank article template and the following error at the top of the page:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home//public_html/site.com/functions.php on line 26
```

Line 26 and down reads

```
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if(ENABLE_REWRITE == 1) $path=' &raquo; <a href="'.DOC_ROOT.'/'.$row['nameurl'].'/page_1/">'.$row['name'].'</a>'.$path;
        if(ENABLE_REWRITE == 0) $path=' &raquo; <a href="index.php?page=1&category='.$id.'">'.$row['name'].'</a>'.$path;
        if($row['parent']==0) $f=1;
        else $id=$row['parent'];
    } else {
        return ' - ';
    }
}
return $path;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's the full code, as requested by King Skippus

```
<?php
/*function get_folders_path($id) {
    $f=0;
    $path='';
    while($f==0)
    {
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT name, parent FROM categories WHERE id=$id");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $path=' &raquo; '.$row['name'].$path;
            if($row['parent']==0) $f=1;
            else $id=$row['parent'];
        } else {
            return ' - ';
        }
    }
    return $path;
}*/

function get_folders_path($id) {
    $f=0;
    $path='';
    while($f==0)
    {
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=$id");
        if($result !== FALSE && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
            if(ENABLE_REWRITE == 1) $path=' &raquo; <a       href="'.DOC_ROOT.'/'.$row['nameurl'].'/page_1/">'.$row['name'].'</a>'.$path;
            if(ENABLE_REWRITE == 0) $path=' &raquo; <a href="index.php?page=1&category='.$id.'">'.$row['name'].'</a>'.$path;
            if($row['parent']==0) $f=1;
            else $id=$row['parent'];
        } else {
            return ' - ';
        }
    }
    return $path;
}

function get_categories_tree($id) {
    static $categs = array ();
    static $level=0;
    $level++;

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent=$id");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $categs[$row['id']][0] = $row['id'];
        $categs[$row['id']][1] = '/'.$row['nameurl'];
        $categs[$row['id']][2] = str_repeat('&nbsp;&nbsp;', $level-1);
        $categs[$row['id']][3] = $row['name'];
        get_categories_tree($row['id']);
    }
    $level--; 
    return $categs;
}

function get_cats($id) {
    $categs = array ();
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent=$id");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $categs[$row['id']][0] = $row['id'];
        $categs[$row['id']][1] = '/'.$row['nameurl'];
//      $categs[$row['id']][2] = str_repeat('&nbsp;&nbsp;', $level-1);
        $categs[$row['id']][3] = $row['name'];
    }
    return $categs;
}

/*function login() {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
       header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
       header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
       return false;
    } else {
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}' AND password='{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']}'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) return true;
        else {
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            return false;
        }
    }
}*/

function login() {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SESSION['AUTH_PASS'])) return false;
    else {
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE     login='{$_SESSION['AUTH_USER']}' AND password='{$_SESSION['AUTH_PASS']}'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}

function get_categories($id) {
    static $categs = array ("0" => "[Top]");
    static $level=0;
    $level++;

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent=$id");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $categs[$row['id']] = str_repeat('|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $level-1).'|___'.$row['name'];
        get_categories($row['id']);
    }
    $level--; 
    return $categs;
}

function get_parent_name($id) {
    if($id!=0) {
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id=$id");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $row['name'];
        }
        else return '-';
    }
    else return 'Top';
}
function getcatname($id, $table)
{
        $r=mysql_query("SELECT title FROM $table WHERE id='$id'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($r)>0) {
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($r);
            return $row['title'];
        }
    else
        return "-";
}
?>
```

Comment: It's more of a question for ServerFault but turn off display_errors in your PHP installation. Also follow what Marc B said in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your query failed, and you have no error handling. Your basic bare-bones query sequence should be:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you assume the query succeeded and blindly use `$result` later, you tend to get the type of errors you do, as mysql_query will return a boolean FALSE when something goes boom. That FALSE is not a valid statement handle, so the subsequent num_rows/fetch calls will also go boom.

Never assume a query has succeeded. Even if your sql syntax is 100% perfect, there's far too many other reasons for failure to NOT check.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
```

with

```
if($result === FALSE) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
else if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    // Query was valid, but no rows returned. Take appropriate action.
}
```

**EDIT**

For troubleshooting purposes, what does it display if you change the function to this instead?  Please be aware that this will intentionally break your site, but it will provide data that is useful for troubleshooting.

```
function get_folders_path($id) {
    $f=0;
    $path='';
    while($f==0)
    {
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=$id");
        die(sprintf("Value of id: %s, MySQL Error: %s",
            var_dump($id, true), var_dump(mysql_error($result), true)));
        // Leave the rest of your function as-is, just insert the line above.
```

Comment: Kin Skippus: that got rid of the error, but it still draws a blank template.  Is there a way to redirect it to \ ?

Comment: Sure, just check for FALSE to see if the query didn't complete successfully and take whatever appropriate action is necessary.  I've edited my answer above to redirect to the document root.

Comment: I'm afraid that created more problems.  Because articles are stored alphabetically, there are two ways to acess them:

site.com/article.html

and

site.com/O/page_1/article.html  (for articles that start with an O)

When I implemented your code, a broken URL in the second scenario (e.g. site.com/O/page_1/badname.html) results in a site timeout.

Also, site.com/O.html results in a timeout now too.

Comment: Can you post the code that contains your query?  I have a suspect that, as Marc B indicated above, you're doing something that is generating an invalid query.  If you can fix that, it will probably solve your issue.

Comment: The code wasn't written by hand originally.  I inherited this site from someone who used a WYSIWYG tool to build the logic.  I see directories for smarty and ckeditor--not sure what those do.

Comment: Can I post the entire functions.php on here?

Comment: What I'm particularly interested in is how you're getting $result. I'm assuming it's coming from a call to mysql_query().  What exactly is that query that it's running?  What I'm thinking is that you're pumping a variable into your query that probably isn't set, something like SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col = $value; but $value isn't set, so your query is ending up being something like SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col = ; and it's causing $result to come out FALSE instead of having zero rows.

Comment: I'd suggest dropping an var_dump($id); above your mysql_query statement.  I'd bet dollars to doughnuts that what's happening is that your $id value is set to something that doesn't evaluate to a string, like null or false.  Alternatively you could drop something like if (!$id) $id = 0; above it to ensure that id has a valid value. At some point, you need to look into using what's called a parameterized query, because if you're not sanitizing $id before running that query, it's a HUGE security risk of SQL injection.

Comment: I've posted the full code above.  Again, this was created by an ancient CMS articles editor and then probably edited by hand by someone on top of that.  I am not well versed in PHP or SQL, unfortunately.

Comment: Please see my edit above to add debugging information.  Note that while that line is in your code it will cause your site to not work, but print out debugging information that I think would help.

Comment: I edited the post above that we're commenting on showing the location.

Comment: string(1) "4" bool(true) 
    Warning: mysql_error(): supplied resource is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/public_html/site.com/functions.php on line 28
   bool(false) bool(true) Value of id: , MySQL Error:

Comment: line 28 is var_dump($id, true), var_dump(mysql_error($result), true))); that I just added

Comment: What happens if you run that query directly on the SQL server?  SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=4

Comment: If you mean put it in the URL, can you please give me more specific instructions?

Comment: I mean run it using a tool such as the free MySQL Workbench, or even using the command line client.  Everything I'm seeing indicates that you have some kind of error in the query.  I can tell that it's syntactically correct--as long as you really have a table named categories and a column named id, it _should_ work.  Maybe you are opening the wrong database, or selecting the wrong instance to run the query against?  The query that is failing though is the exact query above: SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=4

Comment: This is over my head, unfortunately, so I am going to close this out.  Thanks for helping me get rid of the error.